# FB API inserting user_id that belongs to Open User account

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

This is easily the most bizarre problem that I've ever run into while using the FB api. Maybe I'm just too much of a n00b with their API, but here goes.

I'm using the login button for my site. Upon click, the user will be presented with a pop up from FB telling them some basic info about my app (basic details, number of active users and permissions that it is requesting)

That's all fine and dandy. If the user accepts the app, the page will be reloaded and their info that is being requested from the app will be inserted into the DB and a session will be created.

```
session_start();
require_once("model/functions.php");
require_once("controller.php"); 
require_once("model/facebook_api/src/facebook.php");

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
            'appId' => '123456789',
            'secret' => '123456789',
            'cookie' => true
        ));

        $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
        $facebook->setAccessToken($access_token);

        if($access_token != "") 
        {
            $user = $facebook->getUser();

            if($user != 0)
            {
                $user_profile = $facebook->api("/".$user);  

                $fb_id = $user;
                $fb_first_name = $user_profile['first_name'];
                $fb_last_name = $user_profile['last_name'];
                $fb_email = $user_profile['email'];

//              The FB user_id and all of their other info is correct. Seriously!! 
                echo $fb_id."<br />";
                print_r($user_profile);

//              Query the DB to see if this person's info from FB is in there
                $query = "SELECT * 
                        FROM users 
                        WHERE fb_id = :fb_id";
                $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
                $stmt->execute(array(':fb_id' => $fb_id));
                $count = $stmt->rowCount();

                if($count == 1)
                {
                    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                    {
                        $_SESSION['id']      = $row['user_id'];
                        $_SESSION['fb_id']   = $row['fb_id'];
                        $_SESSION['first']   = $row['first_name'];  
                        $_SESSION['last']    = $row['last_name'];
                        $_SESSION['email']   = $row['email'];   
                        $_SESSION['photo']   = $row['photo'];   
                        $_SESSION['accuracy'] = $row['accuracy_rate'];
                    }
                } else
                {   
                    $img_data = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$fb_id.'/picture?type=large');
                    $save_path = 'img/profile_pics/large/';
                    file_put_contents($save_path.''.$fb_id.'.jpg', $img_data);

                    $insert = "INSERT INTO 
                            users 
                            (first_name, 
                            last_name, 
                            email, 
                            photo, 
                            fb_id, 
                            accuracy_rate, 
                            date_joined, 
                            date_joined_int) 
                            VALUES 
                            (:first_name, 
                            :last_name, 
                            :email, 
                            :photo, 
                            :fb_id, 
                            :points, 
                            :date_joined, 
                            :date_int)";    
                    $params = array(':first_name' => $fb_first_name, 
                                ':last_name' => $fb_last_name, 
                                ':email' => $fb_email, 
                                ':photo' => $fb_id.'.jpg', 
                                ':fb_id' => $fb_id,
                                ':points' => '100',
                                ':date_joined' => date("M j, Y"),
                                ':date_int' => idate('z'));
                    $stmt = $db->prepare($insert);
                    $stmt->execute($params)or die('error');

                    print_r($params);
//                      Query the DB to see if this person's info from FB is in there
                    $query = "SELECT * 
                            FROM users 
                            WHERE fb_id = :fb_id";
                    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
                    $stmt->execute(array(':fb_id' => $fb_id));

                    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                    {
                        $_SESSION['id']      = $row['user_id'];
                        $_SESSION['fb_id']   = $row['fb_id'];
                        $_SESSION['first']   = $row['first_name'];  
                        $_SESSION['last']    = $row['last_name'];
                        $_SESSION['email']   = $row['email'];   
                        $_SESSION['photo']   = $row['photo'];   
                        $_SESSION['accuracy'] = $row['accuracy_rate'];
                    }
                }
            } else
            {

            }
        }  else
        {

        }
```

A row is inserted into the DB each time the page is refreshed. No session is ever created. What's even stranger is that the facebook id that is inserted into the fb_id column in the DB belongs to an account that belongs to a test account that FB uses to test open graph actions that are submitted for approval. I know because after taking a deeper look at the DB, I saw a row in the DB that belonged to an FB open graph actions testers. The ID is "2147483647." That is clearly not the ID that is printed out when I printed out the $user_profile array. Furthermore, after the first time the page is reloaded, an insert query shouldn't even occur because the rowCount returned is set to 1. The insert query is only supposed to be executed if the user is a first time user. Sandbox mode isn't on. I thought might have had something to do with it. But, it didn't.

On an unrelated note, is there a bug with FB's api when it comes to doing

```
$facebook->api("/me");
```

That doesn't seem to work.

```
$facebook->api("/".$user);
```

seems to work just fine though.

Live example can be found [here](http://www.sportannica.com)

Comment: If `/userid` works but `/me` not then this a sure sign that you do not have a valid user access token. For the rest: Sorry, but TL;DR

Comment: I can't help you out, bu this piece of code is unnecessary: $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
        $facebook->setAccessToken($access_token);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook `user_id` could go beyond the supported Integer length. Discovered this on `iPhone SDK` for a long ID eg. '`10000328862128237`'. I suspect that is your problem too as I got the exact same number '`2147483647`'.